# Where does Django stdout output go when running with nginx and Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, stdout, gunicorn

In my my_application/settings.py file, for example, I have a couple of `print` statements, thus:

```
print( 'running settings.py: ALLOWED_HOSTS: ' )
print( '\n'.join( ALLOWED_HOSTS ) )
```

... where does this output actually go on a remote server running nginx and Gunicorn?

NB I am aware this may be an egregious security breach to print `ALLOWED_HOSTS` anywhere, for all I know. This is merely an example: I am at the learning/experimentation stage.

**Edit after AKX's answer** 
I found no way of getting `stdout` to be directed to `journalctl`, even with the `-R` switch.

... after many experiments and frustrations and baffling 502 errors, I finally found a way: my `systemd` config file now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn server for mysite.xyz

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
User=mike
WorkingDirectory=/home/mike/sites/mysite.xyz
EnvironmentFile=/home/mike/sites/mysite.xyz/.env

ExecStart=/home/mike/sites/mysite.xyz/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
    --bind unix:/tmp/mysite.xyz.socket \
    -R \
    --capture-output \
    --error-logfile /home/mike/gunicorn-error.log \
    superlists.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

... indeed, I find that it is not sufficient to include the `-R` switch: you also seem to have to include the `--capture-output` switch and the `--error-logfile` switch (NB I am not clear whether there is a default destination for error output if you don't set that switch).

With the above config file, `stdout` from settings.py goes to the file ~/gunicorn-error.log. Hurrah.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever gunicorn's stdout is directed to.

If you run things under `systemd`, for instance, they'll end up into the system journal which you can read with `journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, using `systemd`. I just ran `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn-mysite.xyz`. There is only one entry since I started the service: "Apr 17 18:49:59 vps46990199.local systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn server for mysite.xyz." (site name changed!).

Comment: I also tried `sudo journalctl -S 2020-04-17`... not there either.

Comment: You might need to enable this option. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#enable-stdio-inheritance

Comment: Thanks again... see my edit in my answer... if you agree with this perhaps you'd like to update your answer to help future viewers: then I can accept your answer.

Comment: Does `/home/mike/sites/mysite.xyz/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/mysite.xyz.socket superlists.wsgi:application` not work (without any redirection at all)?

Comment: No: that's how I started out... and why I posed the question. Are you saying that on your system you find `stdout` output to `journalctl` with no other switches? All I can say is that this isn't my experience.

Comment: I'm currently not near a system where I could try it, so can't confirm. What about `--error-logfile /dev/stdout`? Systemd should have redirected Gunicorn's stdout to the journal, so that might work if you want this to go in the journal.

Answer (score 0):

When you run gunicorn there is special parameter named --access-logfile, which specifies the access log file to write to. If you prefer stdout then set the '-' as value parameter.
For example:

```
gunicorn  --access-logfile - demoapp.wsgi
```

Comment: `print()` statements aren't access log.

Comment: Thanks... this isn't quite what I had in mind, in that `stdout` doesn't seem to be printed out here. It's useful to know though: it appears to be that some of the Django server file output get get printed here, with reports on `GET` requests, etc.